Using the Clover plugin and failed builds are causing Clover to not report results of code coverage. How do we force reporting even on failures?
We are using Jenkins pipelines with the excellent Clover plugin. However, when a test fails, we get the message.

No Clover report will be published due to a build Failure

We are trying to find a way to force Clover to report coverage even on test failures. Here is our pipeline code
post {
    always {
        clover(cloverReportDir: 'CovHtml', cloverReportFileName: 'clover.xml',
            // optional, default is: method=70, conditional=80, statement=80
            healthyTarget: [methodCoverage: 70, conditionalCoverage: 80, statementCoverage: 80],
            // optional, default is none
            unhealthyTarget: [methodCoverage: 50, conditionalCoverage: 50, statementCoverage: 50],
            // optional, default is none
            failingTarget: [methodCoverage: 0, conditionalCoverage: 0, statementCoverage: 0]
        )
    }
}

